# Add myself back in a chat group in Telegram

Tags: chat, telegram

I'm trying to figure out how a friend of mine add himself back in a chat group on telegram. How is that possible? I think he uses an app for that.

Comment: Might have been using [liberbot](http://liberbot.meteor.com/)

Answer (score 3):

He can add himself only if he leaves and is not kicked out. If he gets kicked out, he won't be able to add himself back.

You will have to use the web version of telegram to exploit it. 
After logging in to the web.telegram.org website, select the group that you left from the left (direction) pane.

Now click on the group name from the top bar. In the dialog box that open, click 'Return to Group'!
Hope the telegram developers market it as a feature for adding yourself back and accessing archives of groups that you used to be a part of.

Comment: I'm not sure if Telegram developers would notice this bug if it's not reported to them directly. Btw, is it really a bug? Could you provide reference for that?

Comment: The telegram mobile app deletes the chat once you leave a group. However, you can see the same group history in the web version. Inconsistent behaviour across platforms - bug. Although, it would also act as a failsafe if you accidentally deleted yourself from a group.

Answer (score 1):

A "mutual contact" can invite someone back into a group. The mutual contact needs to have your friend saved as a contact and your friend needs to have the mutual contact saved as a contact.

Source: https://twitter.com/telegram/status/586897156344258560

> if a person
>   left a group, only a mutual contact can bring him back (both need to
>   know each other's phone numbers)
>
> — Telegram Messenger
>   (@telegram) April
>   11, 2015